# Feign Client request and response and URL Logging

Tags: logging, request, interceptor, feign

How I can log the payload of **Feign** client request, response and URL. do I have to Implement an Interceptor? Because my requirement is logging the request and response on a special table on the database.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Feign has out of box logging mechanism and it can be achieved through simple steps.

**If you are using spring-cloud-starter-feign**

Feign using `Slf4jLogger` for logging.[Feign logging documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#_feign_logging)

As per doc, the below logging levels are available to configure,

- `NONE` - No logging (DEFAULT).
- `BASIC` - Log only the request method and URL and the response status code and execution time.
- `HEADERS` - Log the basic information along with request and response headers.
- `FULL` - Log the headers, body, and metadata for both requests and responses.

Injecting the `Logger.Level` bean is enough.

```java
    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }
```

**OR**

If you prefer using configuration properties to configured all `@FeignClient`, you can create configuration properties with default feign name.

```yaml
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        loggerLevel: basic
```

of if you are using a newer version (Spring Boot 3) the config will be like:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        config:
          default:
            loggerLevel: full
```

**If you are using `'io.github.openfeign:feign-core'`**

If you are constructing the Feign builder then you can mention `logLevel(Level.BASIC)` as

```java
Feign.builder()
    .logger(new Slf4jLogger())
    .logLevel(Level.BASIC)
    .target(SomeFeignClient.class, url);
```

**We have the flexibility to customize the logging message**

The default feign request and response logging

[Request logging](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/73164e3e3fcdc54be7f9d8eab068e20078908ecb/core/src/main/java/feign/Logger.java#L47)

[Resopnse logging](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/73164e3e3fcdc54be7f9d8eab068e20078908ecb/core/src/main/java/feign/Logger.java#L77)

we can customize the feign request, response logging pattern by overriding `Logger#logRequest` and `Logger#logAndRebufferResponse` methods. In the following example, we have customized request logging pattern

```java
log(configKey, "---> %s %s HTTP/1.1 (%s-byte body) ", request.httpMethod().name(), request.url(), bodyLength);
```

and response logging pattern

```java
log(configKey, "<--- %s %s HTTP/1.1 %s (%sms) ", request.httpMethod().name(), request.url(), status, elapsedTime);
```

The Full example is

```java
import feign.Logger;
import feign.Request;
import feign.Response;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.io.IOException;

import static feign.Logger.Level.HEADERS;

@Slf4j
public class CustomFeignRequestLogging extends Logger {

    @Override
    protected void logRequest(String configKey, Level logLevel, Request request) {

        if (logLevel.ordinal() >= HEADERS.ordinal()) {
            super.logRequest(configKey, logLevel, request);
        } else {
            int bodyLength = 0;
            if (request.requestBody().asBytes() != null) {
                bodyLength = request.requestBody().asBytes().length;
            }
            log(configKey, "---> %s %s HTTP/1.1 (%s-byte body) ", request.httpMethod().name(), request.url(), bodyLength);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Response logAndRebufferResponse(String configKey, Level logLevel, Response response, long elapsedTime)
            throws IOException {
        if (logLevel.ordinal() >= HEADERS.ordinal()) {
            return super.logAndRebufferResponse(configKey, logLevel, response, elapsedTime);
        } else {
            int status = response.status();
            Request request = response.request();
            log(configKey, "<--- %s %s HTTP/1.1 %s (%sms) ", request.httpMethod().name(), request.url(), status, elapsedTime);
            return response;   
        }        
    }


    @Override
    protected void log(String configKey, String format, Object... args) {
        log.debug(format(configKey, format, args));
    }

    protected String format(String configKey, String format, Object... args) {
        return String.format(methodTag(configKey) + format, args);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**
Request payload can be easily logged through

```java
String bodyText =
              request.charset() != null ? new String(request.body(), request.charset()) : null;
```

but be careful writing the response payload after you are reading the input stream `Util.toByteArray(response.body().asInputStream())` then you have to construct the response again like `response.toBuilder().body(bodyData).build()`. Otherwise, you will end up with the expection. The reason is response streams are read and always closed before returning, thats why the method is named as **`logAndRebufferResponse`**

How to use the custom `CustomFeignRequestLogging`?

If you are building feign client using just `'io.github.openfeign:feign-core'`

```java
Feign.builder()
     .logger(new CustomFeignRequestLogging())
     .logLevel(feign.Logger.Level.BASIC);
```

If you are using `'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'`

```java
@Configuration
public class FeignLoggingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CustomFeignRequestLogging customFeignRequestLogging() {
        return new CustomFeignRequestLogging();
    }

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed information, it is helpful for me.

Comment: How do you plug the CustomFeignRequestLogging to feign config?

Comment: @ManojKumarS, good question, I have updated the answer stating How to use the custom CustomFeignRequestLogging?

Comment: This is a very useful answer.

I just wanted to add clarity on the part that requires being careful when there is a need of writing the response. Reconstructing the response would look like this:


`ByteArray bodyData = Util.toByteArray(response.body().asInputStream())`


`Response responseCopy = response.toBuilder().body(bodyData).build()`


With this, you can keep using `responseCopy` as desired.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer did not work for me until I added the following settings to my application.yml file:

```
logging:
  level:
    com:
      mypackage1:
        mysubackage1:
          mysubpackage2: DEBUG
```

Comment: .. of your feign client declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Feign client builder as follows

```java
@Bean
public VpsFeignClient vpsFeignClient() {
  return Feign.builder()
      .encoder(new FormEncoder(new GsonEncoder()))
      .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
      .logger(new Slf4jLogger(VpsFeignClient.class))
      .logLevel(feignLoggerLevel())
      .retryer(new Default())
      .errorDecoder(new CustomServerErrorDecoder())
      .requestInterceptor(template -> {
        //Set some header if necessary
        template.header("Content-Type", "application/json");

      })
      .contract(new SpringMvcContract())
      .target(VpsFeignClient.class, dataVpsEndpoint);
}
```

And my feign is

```java
public interface VpsFeignClient {

  @RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  TimeRespDto getTestValue();

}
```

Comment: When using `@Slf4j` the line `.logger(new Slf4jLogger(VpsFeignClient.class))` did the trick for me. Now I'm able to see the Feign Client logs.

Answer (score 0):

Feign provides a `Logger` interface that can log the full Request and Response.  You will need to set the `Logger.Level` in the Feign Builder or Configuration.

```java
Feign.builder()
   .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL) // this will log the request and response
   .target(MyApi, "my host");
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Yes, you right but I want to log the request and response on special table on the database.

Comment: @RamiNassar, That was not in your original question.  I recommend either updating your original question with that information or asking another question being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

in your RestConfiguration you need to up default level of logging feignClient and override by @Bean feignLogger like:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableFeignClients(basePackageClasses = [Application::class])
class RestConfiguration: WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    fun feignLoggerLevel(): Logger.Level {
        return Logger.Level.FULL
    }

    @Bean
    fun feignLogger(): Logger {
        return FeignClientLogger()
    }
}
```

and implement your logger as you want. For example logging in logbook format:

```
import feign.Logger
import feign.Request
import feign.Response
import feign.Util.*
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class FeignClientLogger : Logger() {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    override fun logRequest(configKey: String?, logLevel: Level?, request: Request?) {
        if (request == null)
            return

        val feignRequest = FeignRequest()
        feignRequest.method = request.httpMethod().name
        feignRequest.url = request.url()
        for (field in request.headers().keys) {
            for (value in valuesOrEmpty(request.headers(), field)) {
                feignRequest.addHeader(field, value)
            }
        }

        if (request.requestBody() != null) {
            feignRequest.body = request.requestBody().asString()
        }

        log.trace(feignRequest.toString())
    }

    override fun logAndRebufferResponse(
        configKey: String?,
        logLevel: Level?,
        response: Response?,
        elapsedTime: Long
    ): Response? {
        if (response == null)
            return response

        val feignResponse = FeignResponse()
        val status = response.status()
        feignResponse.status = response.status()
        feignResponse.reason =
            (if (response.reason() != null && logLevel!! > Level.NONE) " " + response.reason() else "")
        feignResponse.duration = elapsedTime

        if (logLevel!!.ordinal >= Level.HEADERS.ordinal) {
            for (field in response.headers().keys) {
                for (value in valuesOrEmpty(response.headers(), field)) {
                    feignResponse.addHeader(field, value)
                }
            }

            if (response.body() != null && !(status == 204 || status == 205)) {
                val bodyData: ByteArray = toByteArray(response.body().asInputStream())
                if (logLevel.ordinal >= Level.FULL.ordinal && bodyData.isNotEmpty()) {
                    feignResponse.body = decodeOrDefault(bodyData, UTF_8, "Binary data")
                }
                log.trace(feignResponse.toString())

                return response.toBuilder().body(bodyData).build()
            } else {
                log.trace(feignResponse.toString())
            }
        }
        return response
    }

    override fun log(p0: String?, p1: String?, vararg p2: Any?) {}
}

class FeignResponse {
    var status = 0
    var reason: String? = null
    var duration: Long = 0
    private val headers: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    var body: String? = null

    fun addHeader(key: String?, value: String?) {
        headers.add("$key: $value")
    }

    override fun toString() =
        """{"type":"response","status":"$status","duration":"$duration","headers":$headers,"body":$body,"reason":"$reason"}"""
}

class FeignRequest {
    var method: String? = null
    var url: String? = null
    private val headers: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    var body: String? = null

    fun addHeader(key: String?, value: String?) {
        headers.add("$key: $value")
    }

    override fun toString() =
        """{"type":"request","method":"$method","url":"$url","headers":$headers,"body":$body}"""
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no interceptor for Feign client response. The request interceptor the only available for Feign client.

The best solution will be by using RestTemplate rather than Feign:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate
                = new RestTemplate(
                new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(
                        new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()
                )
        );

        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
            interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        interceptors.add(new UserRestTemplateClientInterceptor());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

And the @Autowire the **restTemplate** where you want to use as the following:

```
@Autowire
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Comment: The question specifically asks for a feign client implementation, not a REST template