# How make feign raw http request/response logging?

Tags: java, http, feign

I have enabled feign logging andgot some thing like that:

```
15:27:15.420 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-229] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#postUser] Authorization: Bearer test
15:27:15.420 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-229] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#postUser] Content-Length: 19
15:27:15.420 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-229] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#postUser] Content-Type: application/json
15:27:15.420 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-229] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#postUser] 
15:27:15.420 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-229] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#postUser] {"attributes":null}
15:27:15.420 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-229] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#postUser] ---> END HTTP (19-byte body)
15:27:16.585 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-117] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#getUserById] <--- HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error (1223ms)
15:27:16.585 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-117] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#getUserById] apigw-requestid: RpKPuhaFPHcESkA=
15:27:16.585 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-117] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#getUserById] connection: keep-alive
15:27:16.585 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-117] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#getUserById] content-length: 35
15:27:16.585 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-117] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#getUserById] content-type: application/json
15:27:16.585 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-117] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#getUserById] date: Thu, 05 May 2022 08:27:16 GMT
15:27:16.585 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-117] DEBUG feign.Logger - [UserEndpoint#getUserById]
```

Ishtere a way to output like that:

```
GET https://myhost/api/users/eac92ab2-682b-45d9-8aa2-435f933b2661
Authorization: mytoken
```

E.g. one request - one piece of output in one place (not line by header)

Ideally there request and response should be output tohether, idealy in single line with escaped line breaks

Isit possible with feign?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58554075/14056755